# Using react-native-sqlite-storage stops when try to open transaction

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to use `react-native-sqlite-storage` to persist data on the device.

But I'll need to use a lot of transactions during my code and when I try to get my instance returned by `SQLite.openConnection` and open a transaction doesn't work. And if I try to executeSql from my db instace it works perfectly.

`db` if my instance that come from `SQLite.openConnection()`

```
// THIS WORKS
db.executeSql(queryCreateTable)
  .catch(erro => console.log(`erro executesql ${erro}`));

db.executeSql('INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES ("Mateus Pereira", 20)')
  .catch(erro => console.log(`erro executesql ${erro}`));

db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM PEOPLE').then(([results]) => {
  const { rows } = results;
  console.log(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
    const row = rows.item(i);
    console.log(`Name: ${row.nome}, Idade: ${row.idade}`);
  }
});

// THIS DOESNT WORK
db.transaction().then((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql(queryCreateTable)
    .catch(erro => console.log(`erro executesql ${erro}`));

  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES ("Mateus Pereira", 20)')
    .catch(erro => console.log(`erro executesql ${erro}`));

  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM PEOPLE').then(([results]) => {
    const { rows } = results;
    console.log(rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
      const row = rows.item(i);
      console.log(`Name: ${row.nome}, Idade: ${row.idade}`);
    }
  });
}).catch(error => console.log(error));


{
    "db": {
        "openargs": {
            "name": "Test2.db",
            "dblocation": "nosync"
        },
        "dbname": "Test2.db"
    },
    "txlock": true,
    "readOnly": false,
    "executes": []
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to use a transaction:

```
db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql(`SELECT ...`)
  .then([tx2, results]) => {

  }
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer my own question when I realized how to do. Thankss @Henrik